# Accounts.validateLoginAttempt breaks user staying logged in after refresh

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I use Google recaptcha to auth user is not robot, this part works! :)

I use

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt((data) => {
 if (someThingThatWillValidateTrueIfUserIsLoggedIn) {
   return true // Will not run google Captcha security messure..
 }

}
```

to make my post request to google inorder to verify the public. I guess my question is what should I use to return true imediatly from validateLoginAttempt. If I remove validateLoginAttempt the user will stay logged in after refresh.

I tried using

```
Accounts.user() // Undef

Meteor.user() // Undef

this.connection // Undef

this.userId // Undef
```

But with no luck... How do i use validateLoginAttempt and keep the ability of users staying logged in after browser refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this took a while to figure out :( , the fact is that the one Accounts parameter contains the resume data as well so doing

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt((data) => {
    if (data.type === 'resume' && data.allowed) {
      return true;
    }
   ... code for doing captcha check..
}
```

Works well!! :)